# How to plot arrays of different lengths

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

How do you plot arrays of different lengths but extend properly on the x-axis?  The code below generates 2 data sets, the second one being shorter.  I run an interpolation over each set resampling the data with multiple samples per data point.  When I plot all of the data the data sets that are shorter don't extend to the end of the plot.  I don't want subplots, I need to overlay the data onto each other.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from scipy import interpolate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

num_points = 100

# Generate an array of data, interpolate, re-sample and graph
x1 = np.arange(0, num_points)
y1 = np.cos(x1)
f1 = interpolate.interp1d(x1, y1, kind='cubic')
xnew1 = np.arange(0, num_points - 1, 0.2)
ynew1 = f1(xnew1)  

plt.plot(x1, y1, color='g', label='input 1')
plt.plot(x1, y1, 'o', color='g')
plt.plot(xnew1, ynew1, color='m', label='interp 1')
plt.plot(xnew1, ynew1, '+', color='m')

# Generate ana array different size of data, interpolate, re-sample and graph
x2 = np.arange(0, num_points/2)
y2 = np.sin(x2)
f2 = interpolate.interp1d(x2, y2, kind='cubic')
xnew2 = np.arange(0, (num_points/2) - 1, 0.2)
ynew2 = f2(xnew2)  

plt.plot(x2, y2, color='k', label='input 2')
plt.plot(x2, y2, 'o', color='k')
plt.plot(xnew2, ynew2, color='r', label='interp 2')
plt.plot(xnew2, ynew2, '+', color='r')

plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

[image: Plot of both data sets]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding correctly, this can be done by using two different axes which share the same y-axis, as outlined in [this matplotlib example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/api/two_scales.html).

In your case you can accomplish this by making the following modifications:

```
from scipy import interpolate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
num_points = 100

# Generate an array of data, interpolate, re-sample and graph
x1 = np.arange(0, num_points)
y1 = np.cos(x1)
f1 = interpolate.interp1d(x1, y1, kind='cubic')
xnew1 = np.arange(0, num_points - 1, 0.2)
ynew1 = f1(xnew1)  

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()  # Create the first axis

ax1.plot(x1, y1, color='g', label='input 1')
ax1.plot(x1, y1, 'o', color='g')
ax1.plot(xnew1, ynew1, color='m', label='interp 1')
ax1.plot(xnew1, ynew1, '+', color='m')

ax2 = ax1.twiny()          # Create a twin which shares the y-axis

# Generate an array different size of data, interpolate, re-sample and graph
x2 = np.arange(0, num_points/2)
y2 = np.sin(x2)
f2 = interpolate.interp1d(x2, y2, kind='cubic')
xnew2 = np.arange(0, (num_points/2) - 1, 0.2)
ynew2 = f2(xnew2)  

ax2.plot(x2, y2, color='k', label='input 2')
ax2.plot(x2, y2, 'o', color='k')
ax2.plot(xnew2, ynew2, color='r', label='interp 2')
ax2.plot(xnew2, ynew2, '+', color='r')
plt.figlegend(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(0.065, 0.3, 0.5, 0.5))
plt.show()
```

This will give you something that looks like

[image: Output from modified code]

### Edit

In order to properly display the legend you can construct one legend for all the subplots, as outlined in [this demo](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/figlegend_demo.html). Note that using this method will require some manhandling of the bounding box for the legend, and there are much cleaner ways to do this than specifying a 4-tuple of floats as I have in the line

```
plt.figlegend(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(0.065, 0.3, 0.5, 0.5))
```

Comment: Oh, how interesting! I didn't know you could have multiple axises on the same plot. I think I understand now.  Thank you!

Comment: @DebraGracePeri The only issue here is the legend is not correct, but I will post an edit where the legend is generated correctly

Comment: @DebraGracePeri The edited answer should correctly display the legend, though you may need to change the `bbox_to_anchor` depending on exactly how the figure is displayed

Comment: I think I can figure out how to find the best location for the legend, the main problem is solved and works really well.  Thanks!

Comment: @DebraGracePeri Thanks for accepting my answer, I'm glad I could help - if you find an answer useful you can also upvote it now that you have more than 15 reputation. Welcome to SO

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to SO and am learning how this all works.  I think I "upvoted" your answer.